# Android - How to get only my own SharedPreferences

Tags: android

My app can backup and restore all my data, including the shared preference values. However, when I get all my shared preferences, I also get two with the names "drt" and "drt_ts". I've discovered these are from Admob.

Is there any way for me to iterate through the preferences and get ONLY the one ones my own app has created? There doesn't seem to be any concept of owner or creator.

Comment: Why are you iterating through shared preferences? They're designed for key/value pairs

Comment: I do use it mostly by key. However, when I back up my data, I iterate through the entire set and save them along with the backup. On restore, I can restore the preferences as well as the data. And that's why I raised the question - backup of all preferences is OK, but restoring values that belong to an external library may screw things up or may not - and mostly, the authors don't document such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have your own **SharedPreferences**, that is separate from the Default one for your app you should consider using `SharedPreferences.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`. The BackupHandler has support for multiple SharedPreferences files.

If you want to have AdMob save their preferences somewhere else then that is a different question, maybe it is possible, check with the documentation for AdMob?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: Aah - so Admob is using that because it's the default, and I can use something other than the default? Is there some way to figure out which one is mine and which is Google's (other than looking at Key names)

Comment: I am pretty sure it is neither yours nor Google's since the default SharedPreferences belongs to the App itself and any code that invokes it from your App's Context will be have the context/app itself as "owner". You will not most likely not get any higher granularity than that I am afraid.